# Does the faction I align with change the story?

Tags: just-cause-2

Does the faction I align with towards the end of the game change the outcome of the story at all (or, for that matter, the resulting Mercenary Mode)? Or does it simply change the soldiers who fight alongside of me during the final two agency missions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, the story is the same no matter what.  Whoever you pick merely provides backup during the last assault on the base.